# How can I set IRCD-Hybrid server password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, irc

I have been struggling with this for days, is there a way to set up a password for an ircd-hybrid server so that no one can connect to it without first entering a password? I have the server up and running. I can connect to it, and create rooms perfectly. I just need to password protect it.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the file `/etc/ircd-hybrid/ircd.conf`.

Find the section `auth { ... }`.

Set the `password = "some password"` in there.

Restart the service!

Comment: I have the same problem, but this doesn't work. If I put `password="..."` you just can't connect at all anymore, not even with the password. I tried both plaintext and the output of `mkpasswd`. I must be missing something stupid, of course, but what?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the "some password" in the auth section is the output of `/usr/bin/mkpasswd`.

I had problems running `mkpasswd` as root and it not matching up properly.